# PHP How to remove numbers like [3][2][4] from string using php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a text string that contain some references numbers like **[3][2][4]** or **[1]** or **[5][7]**

can you please help me removing all numbers between brackets ex. **[4]** from that string

using regular expressions Regex ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do a preg replace on `/\[\d\]/` and replace it with `''`

```
$s = preg_replace( '#\[\d+\]#', '', $context );
```

I believe that will kill multiple occurrences.

Comment: He didn't really specify but sure.

Comment: While it would be more typing, you'll have less runtime overhead by using `str_replace`. I'd go with meder, he isn't expecting more than one number contained in brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asks to remove numbers between the brackets and not the brackets themselves, I think this would be what he is looking for:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])/', '', $string);
```